# iptables rule not working with AWS NLB and Elastic IP, works using EC2 Instance public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iptables, firewall, amazon-elb

I'm at a bit of a loss.

First some context: I've got an AWS EC2 Instance behind an NLB. The NLB is using an Elastic IP. The EC2 Instance is running a DNS server and listening on UDP and TCP 53. The NLB is setup for TCP and UDP port 53. The instance is in a Target Group and healthy in the eyes of the NLB (and serving requests as expected).

Problem I'm trying to solve: I want to ensure I drop all DNS queries for record type `ANY` (as well as a few other rules to rate limit and filter) so I've added the following `iptables` rules:

```
$ iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -m string \
    --hex-string "|0000FF0001|" --algo bm --from 40 -j DROP

$ iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -m string \
    --hex-string "|0000FF0001|" --algo bm --from 52 -j DROP

$ iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -m string \
    --hex-string "|0000FF0001|" --algo bm --from 40 -j LOG \
    --log-prefix "BLOCKED ANY: "

$ iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -m string \
    --hex-string "|0000FF0001|" --algo bm --from 52 -j LOG \
    --log-prefix "BLOCKED ANY: "
```

Now for the problem...

If I try `dig some.domain -t any @public.ip.of.instance` my query is blocked and I see the log entry in `/var/log/kern.log` as expected.

If I try `dig some.domain -t any @elastic.ip.on.nlb` the request is not blocked and I get a response. No log entry in `kern.log`.

The weirdest part for me is that I tried taking the NLB out of the picture and assigned the same Elastic IP to the instance directly. Same result - the `ANY` query sent to the `EIP` is not dropped even with the above `iptables` rules in place. The same `ANY` query sent from another instance using the private IP instead of the `EIP` is dropped as expected.

I've tried the same rules in the `nat` (also using the `PREROUTING` chain) and `filter` (using the `INPUT` chain) tables. Am I missing something obvious in my `iptables` rules?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to capture the packets in both cases with `tcpdump` (cli) or `wireshark` (gui) and compare them. Does the DNS payload differ? Do any offsets perhaps differ? BTW you can capture the DNS traffic on the instance and save it to *pcap file* using `tcpdump -w dump.pcap -s 0 -nn ... port 53` and then analyse the pcap file in `wireshark` on your desktop. Let us know what you find :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking around ServerFault I found this answer - [iptables drop packet by hex string match](https://serverfault.com/questions/404081/iptables-drop-packet-by-hex-string-match) which shows spaces between the hex values, I'd suggest trying that:

#### Example from that question:

```
$ iptables --append INPUT --match string --algo kmp \
    --hex-string '|f4 6d 04 25 b2 02 00 0a|' --jump ACCEPT
```

#### So change up your examples like so:

```
$ iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -m string \
    --hex-string "|00 00 FF 00 01|" --algo bm --from 40 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok well after ***many*** hours of troubleshooting it looks like the short answer is that it was working all along...

I ran tcpdump on the EC2 Instance behind the NLB (`tcpdump udp port 53 -X -nn`). Then from my Macbook (Catalina 10.15.2) I ran `dig some.domain -t any @elastic.ip.on.nlb` and not only did I get a response but the query never even showed up in the packet capture on the EC2 Instance. There is only one EC2 Instance behind the NLB using the Elastic IP I used in the dig query. Being thoroughly weirded out, I then ran the same dig command on an Ubuntu machine and also on a Windows 10 computer. Both of those queries timed out (filtered properly by iptables), I saw them in the tcpdump, and the log message was in /var/log/kern.log as expected. I go back to my Macbook run the same dig command and it still returns an answer and nothing in tcpdump... wtf!

I rebooted my Macbook, checked for the one millionth time I was using the right IPs and the same query, tried different domains, and probably a hundred other things. I am at a total loss why this seems to return a response with nothing in the packet capture coming from my Macbook.

So ultimately it seems like a strangely isolated issue (maybe some Apple lameness going on...) and not some weird packet mangling being done by AWS or a busted iptables rule like I initially thought. So the real answer is: try it out on multiple machines before posting to StackExchange.

EDIT: To clarify. I do see the query in tcpdump from my Macbook (and it times out as expected) if I use the public IP of the instance and not the EIP. It's only with the EIP I do not see the query and it returns a response...

*Also, I'm not sure if this should be an answer post or if I should have just amended my initial post. Mods do with it what you will!*